# Issue with Copy Activity Metadata

Tags: azure-data-factory

The Copy Data Activity Which used to show the number of rows written isnt showing up any more.

[image]
Is there any option in the copy activity to make sure it reflects the number of rows written.

Answer (score 0):

- Be it debug of the pipeline, or a triggered pipeline run, you can check the output of the `copy data` activity to conclude whether the data read is equal to data written or not.
- Let's say it is a pipeline run. Navigate to monitor section and click on the pipeline.

[image]

- Now, the activity run dialog opens up. There you can monitor from the activity debug output whether the data read is equal to data written or not:

[image]

**NOTE:** The above is for blob to blob copy. For your source and sink, there will be similar activity output data that might contain the required information (like rows read and rows written). The following is an example for Azure SQL database to blob:

[image]

Comment: I have tried doing the same. But the Data Written/Rows Copied isn't showing up anywhere.

I am observing this problem only in my development environment. We have the exact same code in production environment where I am able to observe the data Written.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed some unusual behavior and double-checked the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-monitoring?tabs=data-factory#monitor-programmatically

The documentation states the following regarding rowsRead and rowsCopied:

> This metric does not apply when copying files as-is without parsing
> them, for example, when the source and sink datasets are in binary
> format or another format type with identical settings.

I'm not sure if this information may be helpful to you, but it clarified my doubt